# Is there any way to search for code inside CodeCommit repositories?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I do have access to dozens of repos in the AWS Console but when trying to find "inspiration" by looking at specific pieces of code, say, *"I know there's somewhere a way to configure sls to create an API Gateway..."* kinda moment, it'd be nice to actually search for a string in all repos.

Comment: Is there any updates about this?

Comment: @Tatiana Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, AWS don't have a solution for code searching, but you can try [Sourcegraph](https://docs.sourcegraph.com/admin/install). The instalation and configuration is very easy.

From the documentation:

> It takes less than a minute to run and install Sourcegraph using Docker:
> `docker run --publish 7080:7080 --publish 127.0.0.1:3370:3370 --rm --volume ~/.sourcegraph/config:/etc/sourcegraph --volume ~/.sourcegraph/data:/var/opt/sourcegraph sourcegraph/server:3.20.0`
> Once the server is ready (logo is displayed in the terminal), navigate to the hostname or IP address on port 7080. Create the admin account, then you’ll be guided through setting up Sourcegraph for code searching and navigation.